# Array function type syntex

Tags: javascript

I was reviewing someones code and he have wrote a syntax which looks like this

```
export const actions = {
    [ACTIONS.SOMEACTION.ATTEMPT.name] ({ commit }, payload) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```

Can someone please explain me what the person is trying to do here? like if someone could explain this syntax?

Comment: Can you please give any reference where you have seen it?

Comment: does this appear in a class/object of some sort

Comment: Inside an Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two thing in the code.

#### [Computed Property Names:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

`[ACTIONS.SOMEACTION.ATTEMPT.name](...` this is setting the method for the object whose name will be equal to the value of`ACTIONS.SOMEACTION.ATTEMPT.name`.

#### [Unpacking fields from objects passed as function parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter)

```
({ commit }, payload)
```

The line `{ commit }` take out the property `commit` of the object passed as first parameter to this function.

#### Eaxample

```js
let str = "func"

let obj = {
  [str]({commit},other){
    console.log(commit,other);
  }
}

obj.func({commit:"the value of commit"},"Other parameter");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is either inside of an object or a class and declares a method.

`[ACTIONS.SOMEACTION.ATTEMPT.name]` is a 
[computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015), the methods name will be whatever is stored inside `ACTIONS.SOMEACTION.ATTEMPT.name`.

`({ commit }, payload)` those are the two parameters the method takes, the first being an object that gets [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), so the `commit` property gets taken out of it.

The method then creates and returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises):

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```

Answer (score 1):

This is using [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Here,

```
[ACTIONS.SOMEACTION.ATTEMPT.name]
```

will be converted to the name of the function (due to *computed property names*). For instance, if `ACTIONS.SOMEACTION.ATTEMPT.name` was equal to `"foo"` your result will be somewhat equivalent to:

```
foo({commit}, payload) {
  // ... function body ...
}
```

which can later be called using `.foo(arg1, arg2)`

*Note:* as we are inside an object the *function* keyword can be omitted.

The `{commit}` is using destructuring assignment which can be used to "unpack" properties from an object. In this case, `commit` will be equal to the `commit` property from `arg1`. So if you used your function like so:

```
.foo({commit:10, id:1}, "bar")
```

Then your function will "unpack" `10` from your first argument object when it creates the `commit` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to solve.

```
`let str = "func"

let obj = {
  [str]({commit},other){
    console.log(commit,other);
  }
}

obj.func({commit:"the value of commit"},"Other parameter");`
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).